# IPTables and SSH login problems when rules are set via a shell script

Tags: linux, debian, unix, iptables

When I put these IPTables rules, I cannot access to the server via SSH. IPTables rules are not persistent, so I restart the server to have access again.

I get this error with these rules when I try to login:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection timed out
```

What's wrong with my setup? Perhaps, there are other problems, not just SSH?

Here it is:

```
#!/bin/sh
IPT="/sbin/iptables"
# Delete all existing rules
$IPT -F

# Set default chain policies
$IPT -P INPUT DROP
$IPT -P FORWARD DROP
$IPT -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

### 1: Drop invalid packets ###
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP

### 2: Drop TCP packets that are new and are not SYN ###
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp ! --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP

### 3: Drop SYN packets with suspicious MSS value ###
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcpmss ! --mss 536:65535 -j DROP

### 4: Block packets with bogus TCP flags ###
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST -j DROP
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -j DROP
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK,URG URG -j DROP
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ACK,PSH PSH -j DROP
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP

### 5: Block spoofed packets ###
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 224.0.0.0/3 -j DROP
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 169.254.0.0/16 -j DROP
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 172.16.0.0/12 -j DROP
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 192.0.2.0/24 -j DROP
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 0.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 240.0.0.0/5 -j DROP
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 127.0.0.0/8 ! -i lo -j DROP

### 6: Drop ICMP (you usually don't need this protocol) ###
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p icmp -j DROP

### 7: Drop fragments in all chains ###
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING -f -j DROP

### 8: Limit connections per source IP ###
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp -m connlimit --connlimit-above 111 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset

### 9: Limit RST packets ###
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -m limit --limit 2/s --limit-burst 2 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP

### 10: Limit new TCP connections per second per source IP ###
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m limit --limit 60/s --limit-burst 20 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP

### 11: Use SYNPROXY on all ports (disables connection limiting rule) ###

$IPT -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --syn -j CT --notrack 
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID,UNTRACKED -j SYNPROXY --sack-perm --timestamp --wscale 7 --mss 1460 
$IPT -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP

### 12: SSH brute-force protection
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --set
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 10 -j DROP

### 13: Protection against port scanning ###
$IPT -N port-scanning
$IPT -A port-scanning -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK,FIN,RST RST -m limit --limit 1/s --limit-burst 2 -j RETURN
$IPT -A port-scanning -j DROP

### 14. Log dropped packets
$IPT -N LOGGING
$IPT -A INPUT -j LOGGING
$IPT -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables Packet Dropped: " --log-level 7
$IPT -A LOGGING -j DROP

### 15. Drop all NULL packets
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP

### 16. Set some default rules
$IPT -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT #NTP time server port
$IPT -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT #Allow localhost connections e.g. between webserver and database
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT #Allow SSH on given port
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport http -j ACCEPT #Allow HTTP
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport https -j ACCEPT #Allow HTTPS
$IPT -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT #Allow DNS Connection

### 17. Forward Rules
$IPT -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT

### 18. Ping
$IPT -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT

### 19. DEFAULT DROP RULES
$IPT -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP #Drop invalid traffic
```

Comment: Hi, did you find out what the problem was?  I seem to have the exact same issue, *sudo iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --syn -j CT --notrack* locks me out of my server too...cheers

Answer (score 1):

### You are setting each rule sequentially in a shell script where the `DROP` values come before the `ACCEPT` values.

When you set IPTables rules like this — effectively one-by-one directly via a shell script — each rule is acted on immediately. Thus the `DROP` stuff will drop your connecting before it ever reaches the `ACCEPT` stuff.

Unless there is a real specific reason to be adding IPTable rules sequentially like this, you are really making the process of setting/updating rules far more complicated than it need be. And you are opening up yourself to locking yourself out of your own server; which is what essentially has been happening to you.

You should just use `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore`. When you use those tools, the rules are not set until *all* of the rules are loaded at once and only acted on all at once, not `DROP` and then `ACCEPT`.

Use `iptables-save` like this to save your IP tables stuff:

```
sudo iptables-save > ~/rules.v4
```

Then use `iptables-restore` restore the rules like this:

```
sudo iptables-restore < ~/rules.v4
```

The `rules.v4` file is where the rules should be edited.

That said, *maybe* you could run this script like this:

```
nohup [scriptname].sh & exit
```

And what that does is run the script in the background (the `&` at the end of the line) and without hanging up (`nohup` at the beginning) in a way that stops the script if you disconnect from the server. The `exit` is what it is: It simply — and gracefully — logs out out of the server.

But because — if you use this `nohup`/`&` method — you are running that script with `nohup` and then `&` for a background task, the shell script will still run, set all the rules and when it gets to the `ACCEPT` rules you should then be able to get into the server again.

---

**UPDATE**: Since the original poster seems to believe the only way to set IPTables rules is via the command line method they are using in their Bash script, here is a basic, solid and relatively simple rule set I like to use with IPTables.

These rules seem to be similar to yours so with only small adjustments by you, that should work for you.

The only adjustments to note are that one should adjust the `123.456.789.0` port `22` line to match any IP address you want to be allowed past standard SSH rules. Ports `80` and `443` are open in this config as well as they are standard web ports; add or remove them based on server needs.

```
# NAT stuff.
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2:80]
:INPUT ACCEPT [2:80]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3:198]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [3:198]
COMMIT

# Mangle stuff.
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [87:6395]
:INPUT ACCEPT [87:6395]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [50:4502]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [50:4502]
COMMIT

# Filter stuff.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [50:4502]
:BANNED_ACTIONS - [0:0]
:DDOS_ACTIONS - [0:0]
:DDOS_DETECT - [0:0]
:SPOOF_ACTIONS - [0:0]
:SPOOF_DETECT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DDOS_DETECT
-A INPUT -j SPOOF_DETECT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 224.0.0.251/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p esp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p ah -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

# Define the banned actions.
-A BANNED_ACTIONS -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

# Define the DDoS actions.
-A DDOS_ACTIONS -p tcp -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTABLES_DENIED_TCP: "
-A DDOS_ACTIONS -p udp -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTABLES_DENIED_UDP: "
-A DDOS_ACTIONS -p icmp -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTABLES_DENIED_ICMP: "
-A DDOS_ACTIONS -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

# Drop invalid SYN packets.
-A DDOS_DETECT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ALL ACK,RST,SYN,FIN -j DDOS_ACTIONS
-A DDOS_DETECT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN SYN,FIN -j DDOS_ACTIONS
-A DDOS_DETECT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DDOS_ACTIONS

# The combination of these TCP flags is not defined.
-A DDOS_DETECT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DDOS_ACTIONS
-A DDOS_DETECT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j DDOS_ACTIONS
-A DDOS_DETECT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,PSH,URG -j DDOS_ACTIONS
-A DDOS_DETECT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST -j DDOS_ACTIONS
-A DDOS_DETECT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -j DDOS_ACTIONS
-A DDOS_DETECT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags PSH,ACK PSH -j DDOS_ACTIONS
-A DDOS_DETECT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ACK,URG URG -j DDOS_ACTIONS

# Drop new incoming TCP connections are not SYN packets.
-A DDOS_DETECT -p tcp -m tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DDOS_ACTIONS

# Drop packets with incoming fragments.
-A DDOS_DETECT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DDOS_ACTIONS

# Define the spoof actions.
-A SPOOF_ACTIONS -j ACCEPT
# -A SPOOF_ACTIONS -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTABLES_DENIED_SPOOF: "
# -A SPOOF_ACTIONS -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

# One batch of spoof detection addresses.
-A SPOOF_DETECT -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j SPOOF_ACTIONS
# -A SPOOF_DETECT -s 169.254.0.0/16 -j SPOOF_ACTIONS
# -A SPOOF_DETECT -s 172.16.0.0/12 -j SPOOF_ACTIONS
-A SPOOF_DETECT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j SPOOF_ACTIONS

# Another batch of spoof detection addresses.
-A SPOOF_DETECT -s 224.0.0.0/4 -j SPOOF_ACTIONS
-A SPOOF_DETECT -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j SPOOF_ACTIONS
-A SPOOF_DETECT -s 240.0.0.0/5 -j SPOOF_ACTIONS
-A SPOOF_DETECT -d 240.0.0.0/5 -j SPOOF_ACTIONS
-A SPOOF_DETECT -s 0.0.0.0/8 -j SPOOF_ACTIONS
-A SPOOF_DETECT -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j SPOOF_ACTIONS
-A SPOOF_DETECT -d 239.255.255.0/24 -j SPOOF_ACTIONS
-A SPOOF_DETECT -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j SPOOF_ACTIONS

# Commit it.
COMMIT
```

Just save these IPTables rules to a file named `rules.mp4` and then run the IPTables restore command like this:

```
sudo iptables-restore < ~/rules.v4
```

And then run this command to list the IPTables rules like this to see all of the rules that have been set:

```
sudo iptables -L -n
```

And that list should look like that example `rules.ip4` I posted above.

Comment: iptables-save and restore are good when rules are loaded to iptables already. If I want to load rules for the first time, I should use script with nohup right? I tried and nothing happened, rules are not loaded. the script file is executable.

Comment: I tried sudo nohup bash scriptname.sh & exit - it locked me out. What changes I should make in my setting, which DROP rules to move? I moved 16. rules before first DROP rules and still I am locked. There must be something with rules and do not know what.

Comment: “iptables-save and restore are good when rules are loaded to iptables already. If I want to load rules for the first time, I should use script with nohup right?” No. Where do you get that from? I use `iptables-restore` all the time to populate an empty IPTables set and fill them with the rules. Just take all of your rules and put them in a text file like `rules.ip4`. I have edited my answer to show you an example `rules.ip4` set that I use. “There must be something with rules and do not know what.” Read what I just wrote: You’re simply doing it wrong… Set the rules in the `rules.ip4` and load.

Comment: Also… “I tried and nothing happened, rules are not loaded. the script file is executable.” If you are trying to just import that shell script via `iptables-restore` that will never work: What you posted is just a Bash script with command line variants of the rules too add them to IPTables. I have no idea where you got that file, but that is not an IPTables ruleset export. They might look different but they are 100% different things. I have now edited my question to add a real `rules.ip4` file. It seems to be similar to your so with only small adjustments by you, that should work for you.

Comment: Thanks Giacomo. I have found a problem on my rules set in this rule which makes me locked: sudo iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --syn -j CT --notrack . Do you know what's wrong with it? This is 11th rule from my list.

Comment: Sorry. All I know is your scripting of this process is more complicated than it need be for adding IPTables rules. I can’t provide any additional help. If you found my answer to be helpful, please upvote it. And if it is the answer that solved your issue, please be sure to check it off as such.